# Are XHTML-style empty tags considered invalid in HTML5?

Tags: html, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

When using self-closed tags in XHTML, you use this type of syntax:

```
<img src="myimage.png" />
```

However, this is perfectly valid in HTML:

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

Is the XHTML-style technically considered invalid in HTML5, or is it still perfectly fine to continue using this syntax?

Comment: You could always pull up the HTML5 specifications. They're not hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you describe is perfectly valid in HTML5.

EDIT: Here's a really good thread on the matter that describes the nuances: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: Can you cite a source for it being valid?

Comment: Well, actually, here's a source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#before-attribute-name-state and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#self-closing-start-tag-state

Comment: I think HTML5 *relaxed* a lot of the manic "tag closing" policies that XHTML carpet bombed the web with there for a few years.

Comment: I prefer XHTML's rules for self-closing tags because it means parsers can understand a document's structure without needing a database of which tags are automatically self-closing. I don't know why they allowed them back in HTML5.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The reason I'd like to keep using XHTML-style closings is mostly because it's nice for HTML to double as well-formed XML in some circumstances.

Comment: @JakeKing - Do I get to make the decision for you? All I said was that they relaxed some of the rules, even some I thought were going too far. Paul Irish has a video presentation on it, you might check it out.